# IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 6.3.0 (Developer Edition) download link

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

Can someone provide an IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 6.3.0 (Developer Edition) download link (or an Eclipse plugin update site package)?

The newest version I've found seems to be 6.1.0.2 and the link is broken, too.
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/iws_update_site_wde.6.1.0.2.zip

I also tried the "Drag to install" way from http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-studio but failed with my Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2),so it's better you provide a standalone update package.

Tks in advance.

Comment: this link work ok for me.

Comment: Then you have problem with computer not with link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same FTP site you can see the link for the MFP 6.3 version...
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_6.3.0.0.zip